# Azure - Running an operation periodically in a serverless way

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have several tasks that I want to run periodically. Each of these tasks will run based on a configured time period. This means I need to dynamically run the task based on the configured period.

At first, I thought Azure Functions would be good for this. However, I've learned that Azure Functions can only run for 5 minutes. They can be extended to 10 minutes, but it's still short of my needs. The configured period can be up to 1 hour. So, a timer trigger function won't work since I need to dynamically set the schedule at which the function runs.

My question is, is there a way in Azure to run a block of code, like an Azure Function, on a dynamically configured interval?

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse how long a function is allowed to run with the ability to schedule a run. Take a look at [creating a timer triggered function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function#create-a-timer-triggered-function). You can use a CRON expression to specify the schedule that you want to invoke your function on.

Comment: I reviewed timer triggered functions. However, the schedule upon which I want to run the function needs to be configurable. That means I would have to dynamically create timer trigger functions, which, I don't think is an option.

Comment: @user687554 You are correct. If you need to dynamically change the time period for when this function is invoked, the timer trigger isn't going to help you. Without knowing specifics, you will probably need another way of invoking. Another possibility is a scheduled message to a Service Bus Queue, then run your function with a Service Bus Trigger. That would presuppose that you have another process creating the service bus messages whenever you know when your next run needs to be.